# ida pro idc scripting issue i can't solve any idea?

Tags: ida

Been fighting from morning to fix this issue.
Problem in my scripting i am using ida pro Version 7.0.170914 Windows x64 (32-bit address size) i know its not latest but i have not renew it.
issue in idc.MakeStr 
`MakeStr(ScreenEA(),endaddress)` this make issue. this make

```
65,"tiRspPlusSecnRssi",0
```

when original result is

```
"AtiRspPlusSecnRssi",0
```

i don't know where i am mistaking any help ?
idc.create_strlit exactly same result.

Comment: ScreenEA returns linear address at cursor. I assume in your case the cursor is before the first 't' letter, thus MakeStr makes a string starting from it and ending at endaddress.